# Displaying bars instead of lines with ggplots (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to show this histogram as filled bar, and not lines, that would overlay. I've tried to change "geom_line(alpha=.5)" for geom_bar(alpha=.5), without success.

What's the proper way to display bars in this situation?

```
require(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)

fileName <- paste("/degree_hist-104-50.csv", sep = "")

mydata = read.csv(fileName,sep=",", header=TRUE, check.names=FALSE)
dataM = melt(mydata,c("F"))

ggplot(data=dataM, aes(x= F, y=value, colour=variable, fill=variable)) +
geom_line(alpha=.5) +
theme_bw() +
theme(plot.background = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), #panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
axis.line = element_blank(),
legend.key = element_blank(), legend.title = element_blank()) +
scale_y_continuous("Density", expand=c(0,0)) + 
scale_x_continuous("Value", expand=c(0,0)) +
theme(legend.position="bottom") +
theme(axis.title.x = element_text(vjust=-0.3, face="bold", size=12)) + 
theme(axis.title.y = element_text(vjust=1.5, face="bold", size=12)) +
theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold"))
```

Here's the data: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/73950/degree_hist-104-50.csv

[image]

Any clue is appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: `geom_bar(alpha=.5,stat="identity")` ?

Comment: It almost works, @scoa! the only problem now is that it staks bars instead of overlaying them: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9q8hq9oxi3evec4/Capture%20d%27%C3%A9cran%202015-05-06%2016.39.47.png?dl=0

Comment: I think `position="jitter"` is what you want. Or maybe `position="dodge"`?